# Android setResult does not match onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on a quiz app that involves two activities: a `QuizActivity` that displays a list of `Question`s, and a `QuestionActivity` that displays the details of the question (prompt, options, etc.). In the `QuizActivity` I used the `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` method to open the `QuestionActivity`, like so:

```
Intent questionIntent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, QuestionActivity.class);
questionIntent.putExtra("currentQuestion", currentQuestion);
startActivityForResult(questionIntent, REQUEST_CODE_SELECTED_OPTION);
```

where `REQUEST_CODE_SELECTED_OPTION` is a constant set to 1.

After `QuestionActivity` finishes, it should return the index of the selected option (assuming it's a multiple choice question) so I overrode the `onPause()` callback:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, QuizActivity.class);
    if (curQuestion.selected()) {
        returnIntent.putExtra("Result Code", RESULT_OK);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        Log.d("QuestionActivity", "Returned with " + Activity.RESULT_OK);
    } else {
        returnIntent.putExtra("Result Code", RESULT_CANCELED);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
        Log.d("QuestionActivity", "Returned with " + Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    }
}
```

I have also implemented the `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` callback in my `QuizActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("QuizActivity", "Received result code: " + resultCode);
    Log.d("QuizActivity", "Result code from intent: " + data.getIntExtra("Result Code", 100));
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SELECTED_OPTION) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Log.d("QuizActivity", "Got RESULT_OK");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I ran the app, entered `QuestionActivity`, selected an option, hit Back, from the log I see that in `QuestionActivity` the result code is correctly set to -1:

```
D/QuestionActivity: Returned with -1
D/QuizActivity: Received result code: 0
```

but in the `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` method the result code is 0. In addition, I also tried putting an `int` in the intent being passed back, but in `QuizActivity` the received intent is `null`. I am really confused. Am I using the methods wrong?

Comment: Your not setting data in Intent before calling setResult()

Comment: Why you need to do in onPause instead of onBackPressed() ?

Comment: Make sure you're calling `startActivityForResult` from the activity itself, not from a `Fragment`. Because if you are performing `startActivityForResult ` from the fragment, then `onActivityResult` will be called for fragment. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564474/wrong-requestcode-in-onactivityresult) for more info.

Comment: @AjayShrestha I also tried setting it in onBackPressed() but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @azizbekian I am calling from the activity itself

Comment: @arjun_sna can you explain a little more?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479886/onactivityresult-intent-data-is-always-null) and the Android documentation, the `setResult(int, Intent)` method must be called before the activity is finished (i.e. before calling `onPause()`, `onStop()`, or `onDestroy`. I tried putting it in `onBackPressed()` but didn't work initially because I called the `super.onBackPressed()` in the first line. Finally, this worked:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, QuizActivity.class);
    if (curQuestion.selected()) {
        returnIntent.putExtra("Result Code", RESULT_OK);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
        Log.d("QuestionActivity", "Returned with " + Activity.RESULT_OK);
    } else {
        returnIntent.putExtra("Result Code", RESULT_CANCELED);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
        Log.d("QuestionActivity", "Returned with " + Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```